# Javascript and shrinking a div section

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div section on my .ASPX form. The section just contains a load of links (standard

```
document.getElementById('Side1').style.display = 'none';
```

This worked great but was a bit abrupt for what I wanted, so I wrote the little routine below (with a little help from the internet) but although the DIV dection shrinks, and the content below scrolls up .. the links in the div section don't move, until the div section is made invisible .... is there a way round this, or am i going about this all wrong (ps my javascript is rubbish)

```
 var originalSize =0;
    var i = 0;
    var ts;
    function shrink() {
        if (i != 28) {
            document.getElementById('Side1').style.height = parseInt(document.getElementById('Side1').style.height) - 5 + 'px';
            i++;
            ts = setTimeout("shrink()", 10);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('Side1').style.display = 'none';
            i = 0;
            clearTimeout(ts);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just need to add this to your CSS:

```
#Side1 { overflow: hidden; }
```